Problems deploying and testing with Anchor on Devnet
I am getting this error when trying to test and deploy my program using Anchor.
Error:
Deploying program failed:
RPC response error -32002:
Transaction simulation failed:
Error processing Instruction 0: account data too small for instruction [3 log messages]

There was a problem deploying:
Output {
status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)),
stdout: "", stderr: ""
}.


can you share relevant code .

The error message 'account data too small for' tells you that your program is larger than the space allocated for it. A couple of previous answers may help

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71267943/solana-deploy-account-data-too-small-for-instruction
receiving the following error using solana cli "Error: RPC response error -32003: Transaction signature verification failure"

